# Text input style with math expression inside

Tags: inputfield

I would like to make a text input with a math expression(yellow background) within the text input. 

Like this: 
[image]

But unfortunately I don't remember what it's called. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a so-called inline cell:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It just looks gorgeous using this.